# What does "cavernous room" mean or look like?

Tags: meaning, phrases, nouns

I saw this phrase used in [this New Yorker article](http://www.newyorker.com/reporting/2011/07/11/110711fa_fact_auletta?currentPage=all).

I think I understand it intuitively, especially with the help of google images, but I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: re the close vote. This is a good question, simply looking up cavernous in the dictionary would suggest a room like a cave = dark rough, crude and cramped. Rather than it's normally figurative meaning of very very large.

Comment: @Martin Beckett: i.e. like a cavern.

Comment: If you are a spelunker, cave has an image of tight, cramped, dirty and uncomfortable, not cathedral like!

Comment: Sorry, looking up ["cavernous"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cavernous) should lead you to "cavern", not "cave".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that the room is very large, and open (even empty).  High-ceilinged, and not cozy.  Echoing might add to the effect.

[Cavernous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cavernous):

> 1. being, resembling, or suggestive of a cavern.

[Cavern](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cavern):

> 1. a cave, especially one that is large and mostly underground.

Comment: Absolutely. I doubt very much that the writer in this case intended any [troglodyte](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/troglodyte) associations such as *primitive, dark, underground*. Large, opulent, light, and sparsely-furnished, more likely.

Comment: @Fumble: More good descriptive words there.

Comment: +1. IMO, acoustics are important to make a room "cavernous".